# How to set onStatus in Spring WebClient builder instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I've got a lot of methods that use the onStatus API from Spring's WebClient:

```
@Override
public Mono<Accommodation> createAccommodation(CreateAccommodation create) {
    return webClient
            .post()
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .bodyValue(create)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError,
                    clientResponse -> clientResponse
                            .bodyToMono(ApiErrorResponse.class)
                            .flatMap(errorResponse -> Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(
                                    HttpStatus.valueOf(errorResponse.getStatus()),
                                    errorResponse.getMessage()
                            ))))
            .bodyToMono(Accommodation.class);
}
```

What I would like to do is to avoid having to use the "onStatus" in every single WebClient call.

Is there a way to set this when building the WebClient instance? Can you show some examples?

This is my WebClient instance:

```
    public AccommodationServiceClientImpl(WebClient.Builder builder) {
         this.webClient = builder
            .baseUrl("lb://accommodation-service/api/v1/accommodations")
            .build();
    }
```

Comment: Since retrieve returns an private inner class in Webclient, you would have to extend Webclient with your own version that overrides `retrieve()` and have it return your own version of `ResponseSpec`

Comment: Actually looks like all the classes are private in the that package for some reason so don't think you can...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found a solution: ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor seems to be what I was looking for.

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {

    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder(){
        return WebClient
                .builder()
                .filter(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(this::renderApiErrorResponse));
    }

    private Mono<ClientResponse> renderApiErrorResponse(ClientResponse clientResponse) {
        if(clientResponse.statusCode().isError()){
            return clientResponse.bodyToMono(ApiErrorResponse.class)
                    .flatMap(apiErrorResponse -> Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(
                            clientResponse.statusCode(),
                            apiErrorResponse.getMessage()
                    )));
        }
        return Mono.just(clientResponse);
    }

}
```